# Strange Issue with Wordpress Install on my local machine

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, permalinks

I recently migrated a site from a live server to my localhost.

Whenever I went to open the site, instead of loading like all other sites in my htdocs directory, it tried to download the site files.

Clearly, my stack is not running correctly.

So I did a migration from live to local with a Wordpress plugin.

This time it worked fine. Until I clicked on the permalinks tab from within the Wordpress dashboard.

Same problem happened again.

Looks like a permalink issue but Google is turning up nothing (perhaps I am searching for the wrong thing)

Really would appreciate some advice or links for where to look.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to Permalink Settings page in your localhost WordPress dashboard and click save changes to update local permalink settings.

I don't know which WP plugin you've used to copy your website to localhost, but from my experience [WordPress Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) takes care of the permalinks for you.